# Why is Swing JFrame always reachable?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How come JFrame instances are always reachable within a Swing application? Won't that prevent it from being garbage collected?

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
System.out.println(Window.getWindows().length); // says '1'
```

Calling `dispose()` doesn't help. It is not even shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no getWindows method on java.awt.Windows, but there is a Frame.getFrames() method.

But I know that both of them use [WeakReference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to manage such things.

Basically the idea is that both Window and Frame class has a field called **weakThis** which is a **weakreference** to the current frame/window object. Whenever the object needs to be stored(for e.g. in appcontext), the weakThis field is used instead of this. (Weakreferences don't stop gc-ing of objects, in case you didn't knew)

EDIT: Window.getWindows is added in 1.6.

Answer (score -2):

This is because you still have a reference to your window, you didn't make the JFrame ready for garbage collection this is done removing the reference to it. For example by setting it to null;

The next example will return 0 if the garbage collector did a cleanup round.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame = null;
System.gc();
System.out.println(Window.getWindows().length);
```

This is example code, which will work most the time, *if* the GC is invoked. It is not guaranteed that the System.gc() will invoke the GC. Dont use this in production code.

Answer (score -2):

Because the JFrame object has not been garbage collected.  Try this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class WTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame jfTmp = new JFrame();
        jfTmp.dispose();
        jfTmp = null;

        System.runFinalization();
        System.gc();

        Window[] arrW = Window.getWindows();
        for(int i = 0; i < arrW.length; i ++)
            System.out.println("[" + i + "]\t" + arrW[i].getClass());
    }
}
```

Comment: No good. You can not force the JVM to run a garbage collection.